# flutter dart how to get object id

Tags: flutter, dart

`WidgetInspectorService.instance.toObject(id)`

toObject id is what id?

And how to get object id?

Answer (score 10):

With this function [`identityHashCode`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.5.1/dart-core/identityHashCode.html).

It return unique id (int) of object.